# Is there a way to silently delete or disconnect an open session using CMD?

Tags: windows, shell, command-line, cmd

I have some open sessions that I can list using:

```
net session
```

I can delete the specified session with:

```
net session \\192.168.1.101 /DELETE
```

However this commands requires me to enter either Y or N to proceed. I couldn't find any option to force the deletion.

I'm playing around with command line tricks but none of them works.
This was my best chance:

```
echo Y | net session \\192.168.1.101 /DELETE
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a /Y should work.

```
net session \\192.168.1.101 /DELETE /Y
```

http://ss64.com/nt/net_share.html

Comment: Oh man! How come I didn't find that article... Thanks! So easy now.